# Update value of master page control on click client page control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

master page

```
<p  class="text1" id="lbl_cart" runat="server"></p>
```

this tag is master page and I want to update on client page control click. How I can do this?

client page code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_buy" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/Add-button.jpg"  CommandName="buy"  />
```

Please solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can attach a click event on the client's page ready event, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#img_buy').on('click', function () 
        {
            $('.text1').val(newValue);
        });
    });

</script>
```